# CName alias in Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, dns, azure-virtual-machine

I have an Azure VM which is using a cloud service. The URL is e.g. Mydomain.cloudapp.net. I have used a CName alias so my domain is mapped on to it so e.g. www.mydomain.com goes to it. However I can still get to it via the cloudapp.net url. Can I disable the cloudapp.net url so only my domain is used. I want to route it through cloudflare. I have a team city server on there and I thought it would be an easy way to implement SSL.

Comment: You should be able to configure your SSL even though the cloudapp name will still get resolved.  I think the cloudapp.net dns name needs to be resolvable for your CName to work - doesn't it? Even if you use a reserved ip and an A record, I'm not sure how you can hide or remove it.

After reading Troy Hunt's blog on doing something similar with websites (use cloudfare to get ssl), I think I would try the free Let's Encrypt cert (but that's me).

Troy's blog entry: https://www.troyhunt.com/how-to-get-your-ssl-for-free-on-shared/

Let's Encrypt: https://letsencrypt.org/

Answer (score 1):

You don't have option to remove the cloudapp.net domain. You can configure your custom domain with your own SSL and start using it (for end users). Unless you are using cloudapp.net domain explicitly, you don't have any risk of using the azure wildcard SSL certificate, and since you normally won't communicate the .cloudapp.net domain to end users, there won't be any risk as such.

If you want to protect the VM, you can use whitelisting so that authorized users only can connect